# Accessing Docker Node API from Digital Ocean

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

My question is fairly simple, but I have no idea how to go about solving it. Basically, I have a Node API and a MySQL containers linked with docker-compose. They are running in a digitalocean server instance. What I want to accomplish is the ability to access my Node API, typically accessed via the IP of the docker container at port 8080, at the digitalocean's public url.

Is there a way to do this effectively? I can post my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile for my Node app if necessary, but I can assure you that's all working fine. I just need to be able to access it from the digitalocean public url.

Thanks so much to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Digital Ocean instance is running Linux and you ran your docker-compose on it. Just be sure you include

```
ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

in your `docker-compose.yml` and opened the ports in your digital ocean's firewall or security group. Your URL must be pointing to your instance.

Hope it helps,

Regards

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks much my friend!